# Como comunicarse con el servicio de WebSockets

Tags: php, websocket

He tomado el ejemplo del Chat en Socketo.me. 
tengo el **chat-server.php**:

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );

    $server->run()
```

Tambien tengo el **Chat.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class ConnectionStorage extends \SplObjectStorage
{
    public function getClientObject($idConnection){

        $this->rewind();
        while ($this->valid()) {
            $object = $this->current(); // similar to current($s)
            $id = $object->resourceId;
            if ($idConnection === $id) {
                $this->rewind();
                return $object;
            }
            $this->next();
        }
    }
}

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }

public static function  sendMessage($idResource, $msg)
    {
        $client = $this->clients->getClientObject($idResource);
        $client->send($msg);
    }
}
```

Realice todo y funciona perfectamente. Mi pregunta es si tengo un archivo en el mismo servidor llamado **X.php**, de que manera puedo hacer referencia al contexto de los web sockets y enviar un mensaje a un usuario del que conozco su resourceId. Algo asi como **X.php**:

```
<?php //X.php

$idResource = $_GET['idSocket'];
$msg = $_GET['mensaje'];

Chat::sendMessage($idResource,$msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que propones para el fichero X.php no parece funciona ya que en la llamada a sendMessage la propiedad $clients no está inicializada (la inicializad en la instancia de servidor con cada nueva conexión)

La implementacion que has puesto parece correcta, como alternativas para hacer lo que comentas se me ocurren varias cosas:

1.- almacenar $clients en disco para que se pueda recuperar las conexiones (seguramente no sea posible recuperar la conexion tal cual, pero es la opción más rápida)

2.- añadir los mensajes a enviar a un fichero o bbdd y que el server envíe los pendientes de vez en cuando

3.- habilitar otro puerto (por ejemplo 8081) en el server al que enviaras el destinatario y el mensaje y el servidor al recibirlo lo reenvía al cliente por la conexión establecidas con el

Creo que las mejores opciones son la 2 y 3. La más sencilla de implementar es la 2 y la más potente y versatil es la3(no 
necesitas nada externo para gestionar los mensajes a enviar)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda!